# Выбор хранилища данных

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, redis

Возникла необходимость выбора хранилища данных. Данные представляют собой котировки множества валютных пар на большом количестве бирж. Все это собирается кучей коллекторов (сейчас 20) (отдельные физические сервера), по которым равномерно распределены обязанности собирать котировки и они сыпят все эти данные на сервер, который и хранит их. Получается в хранилище должен лежать слепок актуальных цен по всем парам, грубо говоря. Т.е. происходит огромное количество insert-ов в секунду. Так же есть несколько сервисов, которые эти данные забирают постоянно (забрал, обработал, забирает новые). Таким образом нагрузка очень большая 
Сейчас все сделано на постгрес, но мне кажется это не лучшее решение для такой задачи... Может быть redis подойдет. Хотелось бы узнать

Answer (score 0):

redis не предназначен для хранения данных вообще. Он как кеш или как очередь...по сути перевалочный пункт.

Для вашей задачи я бы рассмотрел колоночные БД. Так как раз может пригодиться оптимизация аггригации...там как раз различные ТФ можно создавать на лету...

В общем советовал бы вам идти в этом направлении.

**UPDATE**

В свете получения некоторых уточнений можно сказать, что redis не плохо справляеться как брокер сообщений...когда все в него пишут, и читают через publisher-subscribe. Он так же отлично подходит под витрину (push пишут, pull читают)

Но если вы планируете его использовать как брокер сообщений, то под эту задачу больше заточен RabbitMQ
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592796/redis-pub-sub-vs-rabbit-mq

Comment: Кто вам рассказал такие глупости про redis? В нём замечательно можно хранить данные на постоянке. Разве что на обеспечении надёжного хранения данных производительность несколько упадёт, но скорее всего не страшно, особенно на ssd/nvme.

Comment: исходил из того что при знакомсте с этой БД обнаружил, что она ценна как расширение оперативной памяти + PUB-SUB...как распределенный кеш простейших структур...Если ее расматиривать как постоянное хранилище, то ИМХО для этого больше заточены иные БД, например объектно-ориентированная БД или документо ориентированные БД...

Comment: я тоже согласен что в redis можно хранить...Мои системы, которые получают данные будут все равно отбрасывать все, что старше пары секунд. Как я  понимаю, redis не обращается к диску при каждом insert. a это уже лучше чем postgres.

Comment: я не ищу постоянное хранилище, для меня это не сильно важно, если какие-то данные потеряются

Comment: Тогда назначение ему не хранение, как было указано в вопросе, а брокер и отношение PUB SUB. С чем редис конечно запросто справиться...так же как и RabbitMQ например.

Comment: А то что в редис можно хранить я не отрицал. Я просто выразил мнение, что "можно" и "имеет смысл" это разные вещи. что для целей постоянного хранилища есть более удачные варианты. В постгесс тоже можно организовать бд типа ключ значение. Но если при этом не нужен ACID то это будет спорным решением.

Comment: `к диску при каждом insert. a это уже лучше чем postgres` - а это как попросите и какие гарантии durability вам нужны. Выключите synchronous_commit - и postgres не будет ждать фиксацию операции в журнале на диске.

Comment: Я обновил ответ, исходя из обновленного понимания вопроса

Comment: Я так посмотрел, у меня в postgres все уперлось в количество коннектов. Если я поставлю несколько тысяч, это вообще нормальная практика? В инете нигде практических значений не вижу для этого параметра

Comment: Зачем использовать постгресс, если вам не нужно ни долговременное хранилище, ни тем более ACID. Почему не решать вопрос не приспособленным под это инструментарием? Полагаю в этом и причина отсутствия в интернете значения этого параметра